# 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for may have been deleted or renamed

Tags: .net, angular, server, publish

I develop an application with .net and angular 5.
I publish the application on the server, the application is running,
but the problem is when I refresh the application, it shows a problem 404!
how to correct this problem? is server problem or is there a problem in my code?

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for may have been deleted or renamed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Comment: Hello @adam90! Can you provide a minimal working example to illustrate this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Bernard, okey, tnak's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your server to return to index.html

an alias for! you can solve this via setting the **useHash** to true

**`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`**

this enabled the hashLocationStrategy

- > [hash location stratiegy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy)
- > [configure server for angular applications](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your deployment. Add `--base-href="./"` to your build args, assuming you're depoying using `Angular-Cli`.

One way of doing that is to run the command - `ng build --prod --base-href="./"`

Another way (Recommended) is to configure it in your `angular.json` file.

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "my-project": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "baseHref": "./",
            ...
          }
```

Comment: for that, I do:: base href = "/ Portal /" , is correct ?

Comment: Do you use a `relative` path in your code (e.g. ../../) or an `absolute` path (e.g. /assets/...) ?

Comment: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>bb</title><base href="/name/"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/logoB.png"><link href="styles.51.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head><body><app-root></app-root><script type="text/javascript" src="inline.5e.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.ab.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.cc.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.ec.bundle.js"></script></body></html>

Comment: this in my index.html

Comment: In that case my answer will work for you. `base href = "/ Portal /"` is wrong. you can change it manually to `<base href="./">` and your app will work fine. as for deploying again, use my answer.

Comment: tnak's, and i give question :) . in publish my app, i use **ng build --prod** , it's correct ? , or i use  **ng build -prod --base-href**

Comment: Updated my answer with your question